# How CGRectContainsPoint works?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have Rect and origin. I will check my origin point is in rect or not.

My Rect is:

> aRect = (origin = (x = 0, y = 44), size = (width = 768, height = 306))

My Origin is:

> ptOrigin = (x = 201, y = 313)

and i will check Like This

```
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, ptOrigin) )
{
     [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:aRectTextView animated:YES];
}
```

But it gives the result origin is inside, But my Y = 313 is greater than the Height(306) of Rect then why it gives inside? So i want to know how 
**CGRectContainsPoint** works?

Comment: @christopherdrum Post it as answer.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Probably too late, but done.

Comment: @christopherdrum Not too late for my upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic is as follows: The point is inside iff:

`ptOrigin.x > aRect.origin.x` and
`ptOrigin.y > aRect.origin.y` and
`ptOrigin.x < aRect.origin.x + aRect.size.width` and
`ptOrigin.y < aRect.origin.y + aRect.size.height`.

In your case that results in

`201 > 0` and
`313 > 44` and
`201 < 0 + 768` and
`313 < 44 + 306`

Since all 4 are true, the and-ing is true as well.

Answer (score 2):

Because your rect height is 306, but that same rect origin.y is 44. 
So, your rect runs from y = 44 to y = 350 (i.e. 306 height + origin of 44) Your ptOrigin.y is 313, which is between 44 and 350.
Therefore, your point is inside the rect.